# git says "modified: XXX (modified content, untracked content)"

Tags: git

I haven't seen this particular twist, so I thought I would add it as a question and answer it for the benefit of others. 
I have a directory with a few subdirectories and wanted to start tracking it in git.  So I did

```
git init
git add *
git commit
```

But when I then ran `git status` it said, `modified:   LicenseChecks (modified content, untracked content)` (where "LicenseChecks" is a subdirectory.

My question was, wait, how can this be?  What does it mean?  I thought it was a disk quota or some corrupt file or something.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the problem was that the LicenseChecks subdirectory was already a git repository.  The enigmatic message from git gave me a bit of trouble.  When I removed LicenseChecks/.git, the problem went away.  Of course, I lost my history for LicenseChecks, but I don't really care about that, luckily.